# Adding empty array with empty object yields different results when flipping operands

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Best way to describe my question is to illustrate by example :

```
# node v4.3.1
> {} + []
0
> [] + {}
'[object Object]'
> [] + {} === {} + []
true
```

I have managed to find a [WAT](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) talk by by Gary Bernhardt that mentions same behaviour in humorist approach
but sadly no explanation.

Also the equality comparisons and sameness [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) do not help in understanding the behavior.

Same behavior spotted in Firefox, so i guess this should be this way, but why ? What is going on here, why flipping the operands changes the result ? 
and more important why testing both expressions for [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Strict_equality_using) always yields true while we see that their return values are different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case `{} + []`:
JavaScript thinks `{}` is an empty block statement and it's just ignored. Then `+ []` -> `+ ''` -> `+ 0` -> `0`.
The empty block statement is converted to object literal this way: `({})`, so the fixed version should be: `({}) + []`.

---

Case `[] + {}`:
`[] + {}` -> `'' + '[object Object]'` -> `"[object Object]"`.

---

Case `[] + {} === {} + []`:
`[] + {} === {} + []` -> `'' + '[object Object]' === '[object Object]' + ''` -> `'[object Object]' === '[object Object]'` -> `true`

---

Notice:

- An array is transformed to a primitive value using `toString()` method, which is actually an `join(',')`. `[]` is transformed to a primitive with `[].join(',')` -> `''`
- The regular `Object` is transformed to a primitive value using `toString()` too, which by default returns `[object Object]`
- `<value> + <value2>` operator tries to transform it's operands to primitive values. Then tries to concatenate the result of transformation
- `+ <value>` operator transforms the operator to primitive value, then the result is converted to a `number`

Read more about [addition](http://rainsoft.io/javascriptss-addition-operator-demystified/) and [equality](http://rainsoft.io/the-legend-of-javascript-equality-operator/) operators.