# How Javascript is evaluating expressions?

Tags: javascript

How Javascript is evaluating expressions?

1. []+ [] =""
2. [] + {} = "[object Object]"
3. {}+[] = 0
4. {}+{} = NaN

Comment: These are four questions and I'm sure that each one of these is already answered.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36062613/adding-empty-array-with-empty-object-yields-different-results-when-flipping-oper/36062842#36062842

Comment: Thanks @DmitriPavlutin it is really helpful.